# epson ip printer insert cut-line after printing

Tags: c#, epson

I have below code to print a simple txt file on a epson ip ticket printer. How can I add a paper cut line / paper cut?

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
clientSocket.NoDelay = true;
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("000.000.000.000");
IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(ip, 9100);
clientSocket.Connect(ipep);

byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("C:/xxx/xxx.txt");

clientSocket.Send(fileBytes);

clientSocket.Close();
```

Comment: `----------------------------------------------`? If it is plain text this would be it i think

Comment: That would depend on the printer language supported by the printer, which can vary depending on the exact model of printer.